# I get the following error in R when using mgcv package no applicable method for 'smooth.construct' applied

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, mgcv

I am trying to use a gam function (mgcv package) to decompose the response variable pulse voltage into a combination of polynomial and exponential components.
I get the following error:

```r
Error in UseMethod("smooth.construct") : no applicable method for  
    'smooth.construct' applied to an object of class "ex.smooth.spec"
```

The model code is below:

```r
model = gam(pulse_volt ~ s(pulse_current, bs = "ex") + s(pulse_current, 
    bs = "cr", k = 10), data = pulse_data,method = 'REML')
```

Now there are two things I would like to know.

1. One is I am trying to decompose pulse_volt into voltage response from circuits subcomponents so I have modeled one as polynomial response and the other is exponential response(both not measured). There is only one input and 2 output. Can we use GAM to do this assuming no interaction between sub components?
2. The other question is related to model syntax basically I think we need two sets of smooth factors one is for polynomial term and the other is for exponential term. So will this model reflect my hypothesis?

Note: the data is clean and scaled.

Comment: I don't see `bs = "ex"` as an option in the documentation.

Comment: Hello @jbowman Thanks for the reply. Can you suggest me a splines to model exponential response?

Comment: I can see you haven't quite gotten the idea(s) behind splines.  They are not a decomposition technique. They are a curve-fitting technique.  You fit a spline to your data, and you're done, except for model checking, refinement, etc.